# Is tacit programming possible in the statistical programming language R?

Tags: r, functional-programming, tacit-programming

Is [tacit programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) also known as point-free style - an option in [R](http://www.r-project.org)?

Comment: `Negate`, `Vectorize` and identity are available without any additional addon packages.  The functional package has `compose` and `Curry` and some others. Also see the lambda.r package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [magrittr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) package since it seems closest to what you are asking. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) quotes an example:

> For example, a sequence of operations in an applicative language like
>   the following:
>
> ```
> def example(x):
>    y = foo(x)
>    z = bar(y)
>    w = baz(z)
>    return w
> ```
>
> ...is written in point-free style as the composition of a sequence of
>   functions, without parameters:
>
> `def example: baz bar foo`

In R with `magrittr` it could be written as

```
x %>% foo %>% bar %>% baz
```

where `%>%` operator is used to compose a chain of functions, so that the output of a previous function is passed as a first argument of subsequent function. See the `magrittr` vignette for learning more.

The function could be defined

```
# explicitly
example <- function(x) x %>% foo %>% bar %>% baz

# or simply (as @bergant noticed)
example <- . %>% foo %>% bar %>% baz
```

Comment: To define a function: `example <- . %>% foo %>% bar %>% baz`.